# Norm on a Geometric Algebra

Tags: normed-spaces, geometric-algebras

In the literature, for example "New Foundations for Classical Mechanics" by David Hestenes, the author introduces a function on the Geometric Algebra $$||M||^2=\langle M M^\dagger \rangle_0,$$ where dagger is the reverse, and claim that it is a norm.  I'm having trouble showing that the triangle inequality is satisfied;  I don't know how to estimate such scalars as $$\langle A B^\dagger \rangle_0.$$  I believe the triangle inequality only holds only when the quadratic form on the vector space is positive definite.

Comment: Take care: Hestenes (and other writings on geometric algebra) chose to invent terminology, and to redefine terminology in analogous ways but incompatible with standard usage.  This leads to confusion such as this.

Answer (score 2):

${\Bbb R}^m$ has an scalar product (a.k.a. inner product) $ {\bf x} \cdot {\bf y} = \sum_{j=1}^m x^j y^j $ from which one can define the *magnitude* $\| {\bf x} \| := \sqrt{ {\bf x} \cdot {\bf x} } = \sqrt {\sum_{j=1}^m (x^j)^2}$ of the vector ${\bf x} = \sum_{j=1}^m {\bf e}_j x^j$.  The magnitude is well known to satisfy the triangle inequality and other defining properties of a norm, as in shown in just about any text that discusses ${\Bbb R}^m$.  It is sometimes called the *vector norm*, a.k.a. $L^2$ *norm*, on ${\Bbb R}^m$.

Introduce the **scalar product** on ${\Bbb G}^{p,q}$ by setting $M*N := \langle M^\dagger N \rangle$.  The dagger is multivector reversion, juxtaposition is the geometric product, and the angle brackets indicate the scalar part of the multivector they enclose. Choose an orthonormal basis $\{{\bf e}_1, ..., {\bf e}_n \}$ for the scalar product space $V^{p,q}$ used to generate the geometric algebra ${\Bbb G}^{p,q}$.  This determines a *canonical basis* for ${\Bbb G}^{p,q}$, namely $\{ {\bf E}_J := {\bf e}_{j_1} \cdots {\bf e}_{j_k} \,|\, 0 \le k \le n \text{ and } 1 \le j_1 < \dots < j_k \le n\}$. Here $n=p+q$ and ${\bf e}_{j_1} \cdots {\bf e}_{j_k} := 1$ for $k=0$.  Any multivector $M$ has an expansion $M = \sum_J {\bf E}_J M^J$, where $J$ runs over the $2^n$ distinct strictly-ordered index values $(j_1, \dots, j_k)$.

The canonical basis is orthonormal with respect to the scalar product, ${\bf E}_I * {\bf E}_J = {\bf e}_{j_1}^2 \cdots {\bf e}_{j_k}^2 \delta_{IJ}$. Consequently the scalar product of two multivectors $M$ and $N$ is 
$$M*N = \sum_J ({\bf e}_I * {\bf e}_J)M^I N^J  = \sum_J {\bf e}_{j_1}^2 \cdots {\bf e}_{j_k}^2 M^J N^J.$$ 
(The product ${\bf e}_{j_1}^2 \cdots {\bf e}_{j_k}^2$ is $\pm 1$.) When the generating scalar product space is *Euclidean*, i.e. when the signature $(p,q) =(n,0)$, one has ${\bf E}_I * {\bf E}_J = \delta_{IJ}$.  So ${\Bbb G}^{n,0}$ together with the scalar product $M*N$ is isomorphic to the scalar product space ${\Bbb R}^{(2^n)}$.  Consequently $$\| M \| := \sqrt{M * M} = \sqrt{\sum_J (M^J)^2}$$ is a triangle inequality-satisfying **norm** on ${\Bbb G}^{n,0}$.

For *non-Euclidean* cases ($q \gt 0$), there exist multivectors $M$ for which $M * M$ is negative.  Consequently the scalar product is positive definite on neither ${\Bbb R}^{p,q}$ nor ${\Bbb G}^{p,q}$.  In that event one cannot express $M * M$ as the square of some real number $\| M \|$.  However one can still define a norm as follows:  Choose the linear space isomorphism $\phi : {\Bbb G}^{p,q} \rightarrow {\Bbb R}^{(2^{p+q})}$ that sends the $i$th element ($i = 1, 2, ..., 2^{p+q}$) in a selected (ordered) canonical basis $\{ {\bf E}_J \}$ for ${\Bbb G}^{p,q}$ to the $i$th element in the (ordered) standard basis $\{ {\bf e}_i \}$ for ${\Bbb R}^{(2^{p+q})}$.  Then $$\|M\|_\text{Eucl} := \| \phi (M) \|$$ defines a *Euclidean norm* .  With respect to the selected basis, the Euclidean norm gives $\|M\|_\text{Eucl} = \sqrt{\sum_J (M^J)^2}$ for $M = \sum_J M^J {\bf E}_J $, so we know that the Euclidean norm must satisfy the triangle inequality.  Unfortunately the Euclidean norm  so defined on ${\Bbb G}^{p,q}$ is dependent on the choice of orthonormal basis $\{{\bf e}_1, \dots, {\bf e}_{p+q} \}$ for the generating scalar product space ${\Bbb R}^{p,q}$ of ${\Bbb G}^{p,q}$.  The Euclidean norm does not arise "naturally" from the scalar product structure.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C = A + B$.  Then $|C|^2 = CC^\dagger = AA^\dagger + BB^\dagger + AB^\dagger + BA^\dagger$, right?

The key isn't to eliminate those cross terms but to bound them.  The classic statement of the triangle inequality is

$$|C|^2 \leq (|A| + |B|)^2$$

Expand the right to get

$$|C|^2 \leq |A|^2 + |B|^2 + 2 |A ||B|$$

The classic proof argues that $AB^\dagger+BA^\dagger \leq 2 |A| |B|$.  It's not clear to me how exactly one might go about this for the case of a general blade; perhaps you could argue that the $A, B$ must share at least a common plane, and so one can be rotated to the other through a simple rotation, so that $AB^\dagger + BA^\dagger = 2|A||B| \cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between them.  That would be exactly in analogue to the vector case.

Regardless, I don't think you're meant to eliminate these scalars.  Rather, you should bound them.